# Override mapping_types section in doctrine config_dev with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using this doctrine config for *prod* environment:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: app_connection
        connections: 
            app_connection:
                driver:   "%database_driver%"
                host:     "%database_host%"
                port:     "%database_port%"
                dbname:   "%database_name%"
                user:     "%database_user%"
                password: "%database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8
                mapping_types:
                    bit: boolean
```

But when working *locally*, I always have to delete the `mapping_types:bit: boolean` part in order to be able to drop and create my database. (Otherwise I get error 'unknown database')

So I thought I would override the doctrine config in the **config_dev.yml** file by copying it and not writing the mapping_types section, but it's not working. If I don't delete it in the **config.yml**, I keep getting the error.

I guess I could use a config_dev file that would *not import* the config file, but I was wondering if there was an effective way to override the 'mapping_types' section.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `parameters` field (from the parameters.yml files) in order to configure in different machine. As example, you could specify in the config.yml files:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: app_connection
        connections: 
            app_connection:
                driver:   "%database_driver%"
                host:     "%database_host%"
                port:     "%database_port%"
                dbname:   "%database_name%"
                user:     "%database_user%"
                password: "%database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8
                mapping_types: "%database_mapping_types%"
```

And configure in your `parameters.yml` of the production server:

<kbd>parameters.yml</kbd>

```
  database_mapping_types: {bit: boolean}
```

And configure in your `parameters.yml` of the local server:

<kbd>parameters.yml</kbd>

```
  database_mapping_types: ~
```

obviously set a default in the `parameter.yml.dist` as example:

<kbd>parameters.yml.dist</kbd>

```
  database_mapping_types: ~
```

**EDIT:**

Of course, you can specify a different configuration for prod environment instead of the dev as follow:

<kbd>config_dev.yml</kbd>

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: app_connection
        connections: 
            app_connection:
                driver:   "%database_driver%"
                host:     "%database_host%"
                port:     "%database_port%"
                dbname:   "%database_name%"
                user:     "%database_user%"
                password: "%database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8
                mapping_types: ~
```

And in the prod environment you can override the key you need as follow:

config_prod.yml

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: app_connection
        connections: 
            app_connection:
              mapping_types:
                  bit: boolean
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess this means you think there's no way to override the `mapping_types` section as I intended to do? In that case, your solution seems an elegant alternative.

Comment: Hi @Roubi you are welcome! See my update and let me know if this work better for you

Comment: Hi Matteo, no it doesn't work, that's what looks weird. As I mention in my question I use `config_dev.yml` and `config.yml` files (the latter importing the first one) but the **mapping_types: ~** in `config` doesn't override the lines in `config_dev`

Comment: Hi @Roubi very strange. What about the first solution I propose? Have you tried?

Comment: Hi @Roubi and Matteo, the 2nd solution doesn't work in (using symfony 2.8), how dit you manage to get it to work? I can't use the first unfortunately.

Comment: @10us I believe I never managed to make the 2nd solution work. Sorry!